# Scaling multiple columns in a data frame using ddply in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame that looks like

```
ID         Lot    SubLot  test1   test2   test3
dffk        A       A1      6       10      10
wdwd        A       A1      8       6       5
ewew        A       A2      2       9       3
llde        A       A2      2       10      6
e3rw        B       B1      8       2       2
qweo        B       B2      2       9       8
cmve        B       B2      6       5       9
owdf        B       B2      10      3       2
```

My goal is to replace the "**test**" columns with their standardized values. Standardization must be done while grouping by **Lot** and **SubLot** columns.
I thought about using **ddply** from **plyr** pckage. I can do it for a single column using:

```
new_data <- ddply(old_data, c("Lot","SubLot"), transform, test1 = scale(test1))
```

How should the syntax look like if i want to perform this for all "**test**" columns at once?

Many thanks,
David

Comment: using `ddply`, you can just add the scaling of other columns to the command as additional arguments (i.e., `ddply(old_data, c("Lot","SubLot"), transform, test1 = scale(test1), test2 = scale(test2), test3=scale(test3))`. However, the solution from @Sumedh below is more general, and I don't believe you can do that with `plyr`.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work since i have thousands of columns in the data set. @Sumedh solution leads to an error i mentioned below

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using `dplyr`, look into `mutate_at`:

```
library(dplyr)

scale1 <- function(x) scale(x)[,1]

old_data %>% group_by(Lot, SubLot) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(contains("test")), scale1)

#Source: local data frame [8 x 6]
#Groups: Lot, SubLot [4]

#      ID    Lot SubLot      test1      test2      test3
#  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1   dffk      A     A1 -0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068
#2   wdwd      A     A1  0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#3   ewew      A     A2        NaN -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#4   llde      A     A2        NaN  0.7071068  0.7071068
#5   e3rw      B     B1        NaN        NaN        NaN
#6   qweo      B     B2 -1.0000000  1.0910895  0.4402255
#7   cmve      B     B2  0.0000000 -0.2182179  0.7043607
#8   owdf      B     B2  1.0000000 -0.8728716 -1.1445862
```

To match column names that **start** with the word **test**

```
old_data %>% group_by(Lot, SubLot) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches("^test")), scale1)
```

Since you mentioned you have thousands of columns, maybe using `data.table` would be more efficient:

```
cols <- grep("test", names(old_data), value = T)
old_data[,cols] <- lapply(old_data[,cols], as.double)

library(data.table)
setDT(old_data)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, scale1) , by = .(Lot, SubLot), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am open to using any package. Tried to use your suggestion, but when i try to view then new data frame, i am getting this error:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  dims [product 2288] do not match the length of object [4719]

My lot#1 contains 2288 rows. In this case i am only grouping by lot, not by sublot

Comment: It is the same either with a new data frame or reassigning the values to the old one. The code runs with no errors, those appear only when i try to view the output

Comment: thanks for the support. A busy day, i am just starting to tinker with it, will let you know

Answer (score 0):

@Sumedh, thanks again for your help. Unfortunately, your latest code did not work either. I got fed up with scale and got around the issue by defining a custom function defining it:

```
my.scale = function(x,na.rm=TRUE) (x-mean(x,na.rm=TRUE))/sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)

old_data <- old_data %>% group_by(Lot) %>% 
  mutate_each( funs(my.scale), contains("test"))
```

Comment: That's strange, because it worked for me. I simulated a dataset with 5000 rows for 1 group, and 500 rows for 5 other groups. Anyway, glad that you were able to figure it out. One note though: `mutate_each` and `summarise_each` will be deprecated in future.